# Finding A,B,C s.t $f'(a)+O(h^2)=\frac{Af(a)+Bf(a+2h)+Cf(a+3h)}{h}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, numerical-methods

> Find constants A,B,C s.t for differtiable three times function f,  $f'(a)+O(h^2)=\frac{Af(a)+Bf(a+2h)+Cf(a+3h)}{h}$

I know that $f'(a)+O(h^2)=\frac{f(a+h)-f(a-h)}{2h}$ so I need to solve $$0.5f(a+h)-0.5f(a-h)=Af(a)+B(a+2h)+Cf(a+3h)$$but I don't know how.  How can I solve this equalation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Martin's idea: 
$$
f(a+2h)=f(a)+2hf'(a)+2h^2 f''(a)+O(h^3),\\  f(a+3h)=f(a)+3hf'(a)+\frac{9h^2}{2}f''(a)+O(h^3).
$$
Then
$$
9f(a+2h)-4f(a+3h)=5f(a)+6hf'(a)+O(h^3)
$$
and we get the $O(h^2)$ approximation.

Comment: thanks but:a. didn't we got $O(h^3)$ approximation? b. how it solves the problem (and why did you take specifcally 4,9 etc)?

Comment: No, we get $O(h^2)$ because it remains to divide by $h$. We take $9$ and $4$ in order to cancel the $f''$ term.

Answer (score 1):

From the Taylor expansion, we have
$$
f(a+2h)=f(a)+2hf'(a)+O(h^2),\ \ f(a+3h)=f(a)+3hf'(a)+O(h^2).
$$
Adding, we get
$$
f(a+2h)+f(a+3h)=2f(a)+5hf'(a)+O(h^2).
$$
So 
$$
f'(a)+O(h)=\frac{-\frac25f(a)+\frac15f(a+2h)+\frac15f(a+3h)}h.
$$
This doesn't get you $O(h^2)$ as you wanted, though.